# Visual studio Lightswitch

Tags: database

I have a two database tables, on light switch the first one called product and the second one called invoice line items.
The Product table has one column called `Bought Quantity`.
The Invoice line items has one column called `sold Quantity`.
Now I need to have a search screen with the both tables on it, but here come my question.
When I made the relationship between the two tables, then the screen will show the grid with two columns, one called the "quantity I bought" and another column "quantity I sold".

I need to make subtraction and the result will show on another column called "available".
So I have a local property called Available. Now I need code to write to make the subtraction process and then will show on the available.
That is my question.

Answer (score 0):

Lightswitch screens will only show data for an entity within your project. If you want to shape your table using joins to merge tables then you'll either need to create a view in your datasource and import it into your project or use WCF RIA to shape your data accordingly.

Michael Washington has created loads of examples on how to do this, you can find them here:

http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/tagid/21/WCF-RIA-Service.aspx

Good luck.
Paul.